# How to get value of row in mySQL with specific Value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a value of row with a specific value of a mySQL DB.

This is how my row looks like

```
row | email     | uuid | device
 1  | me@me.com |xxxxxx|iPhone
 2  | you@me.com|yyyyyy|iPod
```

So for example I want to get the uuid in row 2, I have the email.

This is how my mysql_query looks like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'");
    echo(mysql_result($result, 0)); #0 is email, but I need uuid, so 1
```

but I only can get the email.

Does anyone know how to get the uuid?

Comment: Please, use PDO or mysqli_* functions mysql_* are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

look into switching over to pdo or `mysqli_`.  but otherwise why not:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

      echo $row['uuId'] . "," . $row['email'] . "," . $row['device'] . "<br>";
      //or whatever data you want.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['email'];
    echo $row['uuid'];
    echo $row['device'];

}
```

BTW start using mysqli_* functions mysql_* functions are deprecated.